# Error while trying to install ATI/AMD proprietary drivers (post-release update)

Tags: 12.04, ati, 64-bit, proprietary

I tried to install the proprietary driver which is available for my graphics card. There are 2 available drivers;

```
"ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (post-release updates)"
```

and

```
"ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver".
```

As the updates most likely were to improve something, I chose post-release updates version. However, when I click "Activate", the installation fails after download. The following message is shown to me:

```
Sorry, the installation of this driver failed.
Please have a look at the log file for details /var/log/jockey.log
```

Full jockey.log is available here: http://pastebin.com/HsZaJXeQ

Is there any way I could get this "post-release updates" working? Or should I try installing the older version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, in my case reinstall command helped. Paste this in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates --reinstall
```

If it doesn't work uninstall FGLRX:

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev* xorg-driver-fglrx
```

Then install driver using terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

If that doesn't work uninstall everything again and try using official script, [just follow those commands:](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/08/install-amd-catalyst-128-on-ubuntu.html)

```
cd /tmp && wget -O amd-driver-installer-12-8-x86.x86_64.zip http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-8-x86.x86_64.zip
unzip amd-driver-installer-12-8-x86.x86_64.zip
chmod +x amd-driver-installer-8.982-x86.x86_64.run
sudo sh amd-driver-installer-8.982-x86.x86_64.run
```

Windows will popup and you can start installing drivers. When you finish type:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

and reboot.

The link is for the ATI 12.8 64bit drivers, to get a newer version replace it with a link provided to you [by official AMD site, just select your harware.](http://support.amd.com/us/Pages/AMDSupportHub.aspx)

Comment: I tried that, restarted my computer and tried installing the update, because in "Additional Drivers" none of the drivers was active. The installation failed again: http://pastebin.com/6jiBxYeG

Comment: Maybe try to unistall FGLRX and then install it from the console:

    `sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh`
    `sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev* xorg-driver-fglrx`

Reboot and do:
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates

Answer (score -1):

You just installed something (updates, some App from Software Center) at the moment the download of the driver package was complete and tried to install. Just try it again and make sure that there is nothing being installed at the same time ;)